# Change color onClick listner in Java Script

Tags: javascript

I want to change my anchor tag color after click on it. and if i click on another link the link color should be in previous color

Like

```
<a href=# onClick="changeColor">Link</a>
```

Please suggest me code for java script.
Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Did you try something already? Did you encounter some specific issues with your code that you would like to ask about?

Comment: yes i tried this one and its working fine .
document.getElementById(getText).style.color="red";
but after click on another link both are in red color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very rough

```
function changeColor(link) {
    var defaultColor = 'red', activeColor = 'blue',
        allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

    for (var i = 0; i < allLinks.length; i++) {
        allLinks[i].style.color = defaultColor;
    }

    link.style.color = activeColor;

    return false;
}
```

and...

```
<a href="#" onclick="return changeColor(this)">Link</a>
```

Demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/ZkPzX/